# How to use a code from a console application to a form application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console-application

Hey i want ot be able to use this code in a form but I am not experianced enough and is wondering how and where to change this code to be able to use it in in a FORM tried to change to public void etc but only get error messages

```
    static String NumWords(double n) //converts double to words
    {
        string[] numbersArr = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        string[] tensArr = new string[] { "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninty" };
        string[] suffixesArr = new string[] { "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion", "quintillion", "sextillion", "septillion", "octillion", "nonillion", "decillion", "undecillion", "duodecillion", "tredecillion", "Quattuordecillion", "Quindecillion", "Sexdecillion", "Septdecillion", "Octodecillion", "Novemdecillion", "Vigintillion" };
        string words = "";

        bool tens = false;

        if (n < 0)
        {
            words += "negative ";
            n *= -1;
        }

        int power = (suffixesArr.Length + 1) * 3;

        while (power > 3)
        {
            double pow = Math.Pow(10, power);
            if (n >= pow)
            {
                if (n % pow > 0)
                {
                    words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / pow)) + " " + suffixesArr[(power / 3) - 1] + ", ";
                }
                else if (n % pow == 0)
                {
                    words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / pow)) + " " + suffixesArr[(power / 3) - 1];
                }
                n %= pow;
            }
            power -= 3;
        }
        if (n >= 1000)
        {
            if (n % 1000 > 0) words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 1000)) + " thousand, ";
            else words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 1000)) + " thousand";
            n %= 1000;
        }
        if (0 <= n && n <= 999)
        {
            if ((int)n / 100 > 0)
            {
                words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 100)) + " hundred";
                n %= 100;
            }
            if ((int)n / 10 > 1)
            {
                if (words != "")
                    words += " ";
                words += tensArr[(int)n / 10 - 2];
                tens = true;
                n %= 10;
            }

            if (n < 20 && n > 0)
            {
                if (words != "" && tens == false)
                    words += " ";
                words += (tens ? "-" + numbersArr[(int)n - 1] : numbersArr[(int)n - 1]);
                n -= Math.Floor(n);
            }
        }

        return words;

    }
```

Comment: It was origanly made in a console

Comment: where do the errors appear?

Comment: You can't make it a `void` because it returns a value. The correct usage would be something like `var returnedWords = NumWords(123456789);`. The string `returnedWords` would then have a value representing the number passed (123456789) as words.

Comment: What are the errors?  There's no reason why this would not work in a forms-type project.

Comment: There isent really an error its just that i cant connect it to a textbox to be able to get the output in a label

Comment: Ive been stuck on this one for some time now and its really driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

You can include this functionality on button click envent or can also call this function onchange event of textbox which will be used to enter numberic value.

1. If you are calling this function from button click then just pass textbox value as input to this function

`// COnvertBtn is button id, on click of which function will get call
//But make sure that text box named as  txtNumber should contain number
void ConvertBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string number = NumWords(Convert.ToDouble(txtNumber.Text));
}`

2. Otherwise you can call function directly from javascript, here you need to make some changes to function as data type of input is going to be text

Regards,
Meet